# Activeadmin bundle error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I am having this error when trying to bundle install. From what I understand it says activeadmin gem depends on metasearch 0.9.2 and metasearch gem depends on activerecord 3.1.0 but rails 4.1.0 depends on activercod 4.1.0. so what is my course of action for this?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
In Gemfile:
activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
  meta_search (>= 0.9.2) ruby depends on
    activerecord (~> 3.0.0.rc2) ruby

rails (= 4.1.0) ruby depends on
  activerecord (4.1.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We're currently working on 1.0.0, which as far as dependencies, moves
>   us from meta_search to Ransack and adds Rails 4 support. You can get
>   Rails 4 and 4.1 support by tracking master:
>
> gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin

Comment: worked. thanks! saw it on the github page. I was following the website which is outdated